# How to pass conditionally a true or false to React boolean props with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Material UI library with React + Typescript.

When trying to pass conditional boolean as "button" prop of  component
I'm getting typescript error:
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'

I attached codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-worker-2l67x?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The TS type declared in Material UI is forcing `button: true` which seems like a bug on their end to me. I would `// @ts-ignore` this line

Comment: woo nice, I burned almost 2 hours trying to figure it out. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLD'R

```html
<ListItem
  button={item.isTitle ? undefined : true}
  divider={item.isTitle}
  key={item.text}
>
```

**The explanation**

In order to show a ListItem as button, you pass the `button` prop. If you don't want it to be button, you can pass `false` but it conflicts with the `true` type.

The other option to not show it as button is to not add the `button` prop at all. But how this helps you're asking? I have to set this prop for "not title" items.

So not passing a prop is like passing `undefined`. Since `button` [is optional](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e526be50c6f80d8044470fdefa65da7d2e0561d2/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.d.ts#L140) you can pass it as `undefined` instead of `false`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-67523398-lhgud?file=/src/App.tsx:1874-1914

Comment: well, I already tried what you suggest but there is a compiler error

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'true | undefined' is not assignable to type 'true'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'true'.  TS2769

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox? Because I can't see the error in mine

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that it works on codesandbox but it didn't work in vscode with typescript 4.1.2 on my PC. strange.   codesandbox typescript version is 4.1.3 (don't know if it related or maybe it's the tsconfig or something...)

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}

Comment: Is your project public (Github/gitlab) so I could clone it? It's not common to help with specific repository but I'll try to help anyway.

Comment: Oh, its ok. I already solved it in another way and its an internal project anyway.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you share how? So it could help to other people? Also, if this answers the question (in a generic case) can you accept the answer so it will help to other people

Comment: Sure. so the first thing I did is using // @ts-ignore (above the problematic line) and it worked well.   Later, I just changed the logic completely so it became irrelevant to the question and that's why I didn't post it here.